# How can I implement Facebook Chat on my site?

Tags: facebook

I'm developing a site with something similar to the Digg bar at the top. One of the features requested is a live chat using Facebook. Is it even possible to implement Facebook Chat on my site by using Facebook Connect or other methods? And if so, how?

**[update]** I've seen that it works with Pidgin and Adium, but what I'm looking for is a site based implementation (think AJAX & HTML living at the top of the page).

Comment: I chat on facebook using Pidgin so it's certainly possible.

Comment: meebo is a service that has web-based facebook chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the Facebook team has at least begun, if not finished, [implementing an xmpp/jabber](http://www.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=110) interface for Facebook Chat.  This would allow you to use any XMPP enabled client to connect to Facebook.  That said, there's at least one [javascript jabber client library](http://blog.jwchat.org/jsjac/) available that I can find.  Although, you may have to implement a proxy on your web server to allow the JS client to talk to the Facebook server.

Also, I'm not sure how they're doing it, but Meebo has managed to enable [Facebook chat integration](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/02/05/meebo-launches-first-official-facebook-connect-chat-integration/) on their site with Facebook Connect.  I haven't found anything mentioning it, but this functionality may be easily available through the Facebook Connect API ([documentation](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect)).

To answer your question: Yes, it's possible.